# Understanding jquery snippet, window.*

Tags: jquery

I'm debugging a piece of jquery and found this snippet which i don't understand.

Would someone mind breaking it down so that I can research the individual parts?

```
 window.specific = $('.' + specific_class);
```

Comment: By prefixing `window.`, the variable will be globally defined. This makes it easier to debug the variable's value (via the console, for instance).

Comment: It simply caches the list of elements matched by .specific_class in a global variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`specific` is defined in "window scope" outside the function. `specific_class` would have some class name in it and it is used in jQuery selector and matched elements are assigned to `window.specific`.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fhckh/)**

```
window.specific = "";
specific_class =  'someclass';

function myfun()
{
    window.specific = $('.' + specific_class);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle, so window.specific is a global object which refers to all instances of .specific_class.  But since you can already target every '.specific_class' i'm curious as to why this is necessary - I'm sure this will become clear though...

Answer (score 1):

This sets the 'specific' property of the window object to a class defined by the specific_class variable.

Let's say that the specific_class variable contained the text 'myClass', then window.specific would be equal to:-

```
window.specific = $('.myClass');
```

Which in turn would refer to all instances of the myClass class.

Answer (score 0):

Basically it looks for a class...

`.` is the argument for a class selector. `specific_class` is a variable which will refer to the class name. Look for that variable and you'll find what the class means.